# Word Interop from MVC Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, office-interop, com-interop

I am new to C# & MVC but have written a simple web application which updates a users Outlook Email Signature.
This application works in my test environment but when I deploy I receive errors around the Word Interop assembly I'm using.

> I have seen blogs which discuss why you don't want to install and use server side Office applications. How can I use the office installation on the executing user's computer?

It is safe to assume that all users navigating to this application will have office installed on their machine.

> How can I create a word file locally on their machine from an MVC Web app which is a simple form? Is my only option OpenOffice XML?

I'm sorry if this question isn't well structured, I'm struggling to understand the concept myself

Comment: you need to create word file first on server than give a download link so they can get the desired file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

If you are building a solution that runs in a server-side context, you should try to use components that have been made safe for unattended execution. Or, you should try to find alternatives that allow at least part of the code to run client-side. If you use an Office application from a server-side solution, the application will lack many of the necessary capabilities to run successfully. Additionally, you will be taking risks with the stability of your overall solution. Read more about that in the [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office) article.

As a workaround you may consider using any third-party components designed for the server-side execution or just Open XML SDK, see [Welcome to the Open XML SDK 2.5 for Office](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb448854.aspx) for more information.